# JSONObject text must begin with '{'

Tags: java, json

I have this JSONObject:

```
{
  "gutter_url" : "",
  "sort_order" : "popularity",
  "result" : [
    {
      "afs" : "Y",
      "release_year" : 1979,
      "album_sort" : "Wall, The"
    }
  ]
}
```

and want to get the Array at the position "result",
so I wrote this code:

```
JSONObject allCDs = new JSONObject(objectString);
JSONArray CD_List = allCDs.getJSONArray("result");
```

But then I get this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
 at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:410)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:179)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:402)
 at de.htwberlin.gim.Aufgabe8_5.getCoversFor(Aufgabe8_5.java:55)
 at de.htwberlin.gim.Aufgabe8_5.main(Aufgabe8_5.java:77)
```

Comment: what is objectString in your code?

Answer (score 16):

You may be passing the STRING to JSONObject with leading spaces.  Try trimming

```
JSONObject allCDs = new JSONObject(objectString.replace(/^\s+/,""));
```

**EDIT:** I thought this was javascript. Try trimming it using Java code instead

```
JSONObject allCDs = new JSONObject(objectString.trim());
```

If that still doesn't work, then show what the first character from the string is:

```
System.out.println((int)objectString.trim().charAt(0));
```

You should be expecting 123, the curly braces. In fact, check the entire content

```
System.out.println((int)objectString);  // or
System.out.println((int)objectString.trim());
```

You could also try cutting everything before the { in the string

```
JSONObject allCDs = new JSONObject(objectString.substring(objectString.indexOf('{')));
```

Comment: you are right, but actually this comma-mistake was just because I shortened the JSONObject for this Question at stackoverflow. The original is totally correct and checked.

Comment: The JSONObject(objectString.replace(/^\s+/,""));
 does not work :((  .replace is only for chars

Comment: What is the type and content of the variable objectString?

Comment: the type is a String, which contains information from this JSONObject:

Comment: http://home.de.napster.com/search-cgi/getListByIDXML?CLIENTTYPE=client&type_id=artistalbum&result_type=album&select_by=artist&select_value=10451807&format=json&count=10&index=0&LFM=N&COUNTRYCODE=DE&EXPLICIT=Y

Comment: @wong Updated answer based on objectString = string

Comment: The .trim did not work. The first character from the string is "null" and then comes the curly brace. That means I my String objectString is not correct. This was my Code to create it:

Comment: BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         String line = inReader.readLine();
         
   while (line != null){
    
    objectString+= line;
    //System.out.println(line);
    line = inReader.readLine();
    }

Comment: Cutting off the "null" works :)) But perhaps I shall somehow correct, how I create the String !  Thank You very much anyway for finding the real mistake of my Code, Thank You :)

Comment: @wong - Pleasure to help. I see that you are new to StackOverflow.  Welcome!  When you please, you can upvote the answer and accept it (click on the tick next to the answer). Thanks

Comment: This `objectString.trim()` fixed it for me ;)!

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I faced the same problem and this line `JSONObject allCDs = new JSONObject(objectString.substring(objectString.indexOf('{')));` solved the problem but it gets just the first element only not the whole elements of the json. How to get all json data?

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Was struggling for so long- The substring Helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Found solution! I got this error when i was reading Bulk APi in Java
so if you are in the same situation then just add following lines.

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two commas at the end of this line:

```
"sort_order" : "popularity",,
```

It should probably be one comma:

```
"sort_order" : "popularity",
```

Comment: you are right, but actually this comma-mistake was just because I shortened the JSONObject for this Question at stackoverflow. The original is totally correct and checked.

Answer (score 0):

**Example1:** Read the [Json](https://app.box.com/s/kl9mk2xpks12mh7w4mz2xpdrrpv4lxsf) text from file.

```
package com.json.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class GetArrayObjectFromJsonText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonText;
        try {
            jsonText = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\udaykiranp\\Downloads\\Json.txt")));
            int i = jsonText.indexOf("{");
            jsonText = jsonText.substring(i);
            JSONObject jsonFile = new JSONObject(jsonText);
            System.out.println("Input JSON data: "+ jsonFile.toString());
            Object result = jsonFile.get("result");
            System.out.println("Result array Data: "+ result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Example2:**

```
String jsonText = "\"{\"gutter_url\":\"\", \"result\":[{\"album_sort\":\"Wall, The\",\"release_year\":1979,\"afs\":\"Y\"}],\"sort_order\":\"popularity\"}\"";
int i = jsonText.indexOf("{");
jsonText = jsonText.substring(i);
JSONObject jsonFile = new JSONObject(jsonText);
System.out.println("Input JSON data: "+ jsonFile.toString());
Object result = jsonFile.get("result");
System.out.println("Result array Data: "+ result);
```

**First get the Index position of** ***{*** **then read the json text data**.

**Output:**

```
Input JSON data: {"gutter_url":"","result":[{"album_sort":"Wall, The","release_year":1979,"afs":"Y"}],"sort_order":"popularity"}
Result array Data: [{"album_sort":"Wall, The","release_year":1979,"afs":"Y"}]
```