# processing JSONArray, JSONObject

Tags: arrays, json, object, processing

I am having the following code:

```java
JSONObject json;
int max;
void setup() {
  size(500,500);

JSONObject json = loadJSONObject("january_2016.json");
JSONObject maxTemperature = json.getJSONObject("Max Temperature");
int max = maxTemperature.getInt("max");

  print(max);
}

void draw(){

  ellipse(max, 10, 100, 100);
}
```

And my Json file:

```java
[
  {
    "Max Temperature": {
      "max": "18", 
      "avg": "6", 
      "min": "-2"
    }
]
```

When I run the code now I get the following error: 
`JSONObject must begin with {`
I understood that because of the [ ] I need to use JSONArray but if I change
`JSONObject json = loadJSONObject("january_2016.json");<br>`
 to JSONArray, I get this error:
`The method getJSONObject(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

I am sure it must be simple but I am a pretty new to this, so thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONObject text must begin with '{'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773663/jsonobject-text-must-begin-with)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding some basics about how JSON and Processing both work.

Let's look at some example JSON. A `JSONObject` is a set of key/value pairs surrounded by curly brackets `{}`. Here is a `JSONObject`:

```
{
   "max": "18", 
   "avg": "6", 
   "min": "-2"
}
```

**If you have a `JSONObject`, then you can get values by their String keys.**

You can also nest `JSONObjects` so that a `JSONObject` contains a key whose value is itself a `JSONObject`. Like so:

```
{
   "Max Temperature":  {
      "max": "18", 
      "avg": "6", 
      "min": "-2"
   }
}
```

You can also have a `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject`. A `JSONArray` is a set of values surrounded by square brackets `[]` Here is a `JSONArray`:

```
 [
   {
     "id": 0,
     "species": "Capra hircus",
     "name": "Goat"
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "species": "Panthera pardus",
     "name": "Leopard"
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "species": "Equus zebra",
     "name": "Zebra"
   }
 ]
```

This example `JSONArray` is taken from [the reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/loadJSONArray_.html), and it contains 3 `JSONObjects`.

**If you have a `JSONArray`, then you have to get the values from a specific index.**

Now let's look at your JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Max Temperature": {
      "max": "18", 
      "avg": "6", 
      "min": "-2"
    }
]
```

Your JSON starts with a square bracket `[`, which means it's a `JSONArray`.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = loadJSONArray("january_2016.json");
```

Okay, so now you have your `JSONArray`. **That means you have to access the data via a specific `int` index.** In your case you only have one index, so it's index `0`:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

The `jsonObject` variable now contains this JSON:

```
{
"Max Temperature": {
  "max": "18", 
  "avg": "6", 
  "min": "-2"
}
```

From here you should be able to parse the `JSONObject` using the functions I showed you in your other question.

You might also just modify your JSON file so that you can use it as a `JSONObject` directly.