# JSONObject must begin with '{' at character 1[character 2 line 1]

Tags: java, json, apache

**First time posting to stackoverflow, sorry if post format is wrong. wouldnt mind feedback on it if that helps with my question outlay.**

Trying to receive the JSON from WU(Weather Underground).
This is the JSON:

```
{
  "response":{
    "version":"0.1",
    "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
    "features":{
      "conditions":1
    }
  },
  "current_observation":{
    "image":{
      "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
      "title":"Weather Underground",
      "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
    },
    "display_location":{
      "full":"Brisbane, Australia",
      "city":"Brisbane",
      "state":"QNS",
      "state_name":"Australia",
      "country":"AU",
      "country_iso3166":"AU",
      "zip":"00000",
      "magic":"15",
      "wmo":"94576",
      "latitude":"-27.46999931",
      "longitude":"153.02999878",
      "elevation":"14.0"
    },
    "observation_location":{
      "full":"Liberte Weather, Brisbane, ",
      "city":"Liberte Weather, Brisbane",
      "state":"",
      "country":"AU",
      "country_iso3166":"AU",
      "latitude":"-27.476187",
      "longitude":"153.037369",
      "elevation":"0 ft"
    },
    "estimated":{

    },
    "station_id":"IBRISBAN101",
    "observation_time":"Last Updated on June 17, 4:07 PM AEST",
    "observation_time_rfc822":"Sat, 17 Jun 2017 16:07:44 +1000",
    "observation_epoch":"1497679664",
    "local_time_rfc822":"Sat, 17 Jun 2017 16:08:10 +1000",
    "local_epoch":"1497679690",
    "local_tz_short":"AEST",
    "local_tz_long":"Australia/Brisbane",
    "local_tz_offset":"+1000",
    "weather":"Mostly Cloudy",
    "temperature_string":"71.6 F (22.0 C)",
    "temp_f":71.6,
    "temp_c":22.0,
    "relative_humidity":"75%",
    "wind_string":"From the WNW at 6.8 MPH",
    "wind_dir":"WNW",
    "wind_degrees":292,
    "wind_mph":6.8,
    "wind_gust_mph":0,
    "wind_kph":10.9,
    "wind_gust_kph":0,
    "pressure_mb":"1016",
    "pressure_in":"30.01",
    "pressure_trend":"0",
    "dewpoint_string":"63 F (17 C)",
    "dewpoint_f":63,
    "dewpoint_c":17,
    "heat_index_string":"NA",
    "heat_index_f":"NA",
    "heat_index_c":"NA",
    "windchill_string":"NA",
    "windchill_f":"NA",
    "windchill_c":"NA",
    "feelslike_string":"71.6 F (22.0 C)",
    "feelslike_f":"71.6",
    "feelslike_c":"22.0",
    "visibility_mi":"6.2",
    "visibility_km":"10.0",
    "solarradiation":"--",
    "UV":"0",
    "precip_1hr_string":"-999.00 in ( 0 mm)",
    "precip_1hr_in":"-999.00",
    "precip_1hr_metric":" 0",
    "precip_today_string":"0.00 in (0 mm)",
    "precip_today_in":"0.00",
    "precip_today_metric":"0",
    "icon":"mostlycloudy",
    "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/mostlycloudy.gif",
    "forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/94576.html",
    "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=IBRISBAN101",
    "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=-27.476187,153.037369",
    "nowcast":""
  }
}
```

This is how im trying to call it and work with it:

```
public static void getJsonHttp() throws IOException, JSONException {
    String output; // contains received JSON 
    String full; // city,country
    String city; // city
    String state; // state
    String stateName; // state name
    try {

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
                "http://api.wunderground.com/api/<MY API KEY>/conditions/q/Australia/Brisbane.json");
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // System.out.println(output);
            // System.out.println(br);
            JSONObject jSon = new JSONObject(output.trim());
            // System.out.println(jSon);
            JSONObject fullJson = jSon.getJSONObject("version");
            JSONObject currentObservation = fullJson.getJSONObject("current_observation");
            JSONObject displayLocation = currentObservation.getJSONObject("display_location");

            full = displayLocation.getString("full");
            city = displayLocation.getString("city");
            state = displayLocation.getString("state");
            stateName = displayLocation.getString("state_name");

            System.out.println(full);
            System.out.println(city);
            System.out.println(state);
            System.out.println(stateName);

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this current code I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:451)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:196)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:320)
    at mainCommands.JsonConverter.getJsonHttp(JsonConverter.java:74)
    at mainCommands.JsonConverter.main(JsonConverter.java:41)
```

If I change the `JSONObject jSon = new JSONObject(output.trim());`
to `JSONObject jSon = new JSONObject(br);`
I instead get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["version"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:472)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:637)
    at mainCommands.JsonConverter.getJsonHttp(JsonConverter.java:76)
    at mainCommands.JsonConverter.main(JsonConverter.java:41)
```

If I change the `JSONObject(br);` to `JSONObject(br.readLine());`
I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 2 [character 3 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:451)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:202)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:320)
    at mainCommands.JsonConverter.getJsonHttp(JsonConverter.java:74)
    at mainCommands.JsonConverter.main(JsonConverter.java:41)
```

both `output` and `br` give the same output when I print ln. its the exact same as the JSON above which im expecting.

I have also tried only calling "response", only calling "version", only calling "conditions" and "current observation"  and since I cant see any [] i assume they arent JSONArray's.

The `System.out.println(output)/(br)` are just in the code to test what prints out. and theyre both the same. except when I print output. there is a whitespace at the beginning that `output.trim()` doesnt get rid of... so im always getting the `must start with '{'` error.

I’m obviously misunderstanding the whole JSONObject/Array.get sequence. or something in the `HttpRequest` isnt right. even though when I println the `br` or `output` it is what I’m expecting it to be.

I believe I have also gone through all stackoverflow threads about this aswell and tried all possible org.json answers.

found this one the most useful for different options but nothing worked:
[JSONObject text must begin with '{'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773663/jsonobject-text-must-begin-with)

open to all solutions but would like to stay within org.json, can get GSON if needed but surely i have just misunderstood the whole thing and its an easy fix..

**EDIT:**

```
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

prints out the JSON perfect as expected.. but:

```
System.out.println(br);
```

prints out the following:

```
java.io.BufferedReader@3108bc
```

over and over again. 
so:

```
JSONObject jSon = new JSONObject(br);
```

wouldnt find anything.

Comment: Copy the complete json and paste it into some browser debugger and hit enter. You will have validated the json and also get a clear picture of the nestings.

Comment: Already done that and it comes up as a valid JSON. i believe i have the process right. call each object in order before i can get to the certain attribute im chasing. but obviously executing the code wrong.

Comment: You are wrong here 'JSONObject fullJson = jSon.getJSONObject("version");' and you should access to values by keys . I will post another kind of solution below , this time not for android :D and with **http client**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead edit and adding code to my previous answer who was helping when you coding in Android , i will add another solution , this time using **http client**

I din't do everything in the same file , but i created two files , one of parsing (reusable) and another one who is using the first one (client request) .

- **JSONParser**

  ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
  import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  public class JSONParser {
      static InputStream is = null;
      static JSONObject jObj = null;
      static String json = "";
      // constructor
      public JSONParser() {
      }
      // function get json from url
      // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
      public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method) {
          // Making HTTP request
          try {
              // check for request method
              if("POST".equals(method)){
                  // request method is POST
                  // defaultHttpClient
                  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  
                  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                  is = httpEntity.getContent();
              }else if("GET".equals(method)){
                  // request method is GET
                  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                  is = httpEntity.getContent();
              }           
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                      is));
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line);
              }
              is.close();
              json = sb.toString();
          } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
          // try parse the string to a JSON object
          try {
              jObj = new JSONObject(json);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return jObj; 
      }
  }
  ```
- **Client**

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  public class Client {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          try {
              getJsonHttp();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      public static void getJsonHttp() throws IOException, JSONException {
              JSONParser jsp = new JSONParser();
              String url ="http://api.wunderground.com/api/<key>/conditions/q/Australia/Brisbane.json";
                  JSONObject obj = jsp.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET");
                  JSONObject disp = obj.getJSONObject("current_observation");
                 JSONObject des = disp.getJSONObject("display_location");
                 JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(des.toString().trim());
                 Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
                 while( keys.hasNext() ) {
                     String key = (String)keys.next();
                        if("full".equals(key) || "city".equals(key) || "state".equals(key) || "state_name".equals(key)){
                            System.out.println(jObject.get(key).toString());
                        }
                 }   
      }
  }
  ```

If you execute the code , you will get this result:

[image]

THe libraries you should add to the build path are :

I downloaded it from here : [HttpComponents Downloads](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution mate,DefaultHttpClient was still deprecated but i also didnt update my build path but i worked around that with HttpClient/HttpClientBuilder.
Now lets see if i can continue with this method. (work my head around it)
(Sorry i cant upvote, only just joined.)

Comment: **Never** compare strings with `==` as in your lines `if(method == "POST"){` and `}else if(method == "GET"){`. Always use the `String.equals` method to compare.

Answer (score 0):

The correct statement would be

```
JSONObject jSon = new JSONObject(br);
```

You are getting the `Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["version"] not found.` error because `version` is not a direct object. It is only an attribute of the `response` object as `city` is for the nested `display_location` object. So, retrieve it in a similar fashion. 
First, `response` object and then its attribute `version`.

Comment: i stated above that i also tried that statement and thats where i got the "version" error. also tried to call "response" before "version" . error came back saying "response" not found.

(Sorry not sure if i can format comments properly.

Comment: Then perhaps u need to put a debug statement before reading from the json to see if this is the json received when you hit that response not found error also.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you start to coding specially for mobile devices you are interested at the final result , without pay attention to what is **deprecated** and what is new .
The library you are using is not supported anymore , read this article [Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

So maybe after read it you would be interested , what is the alternative to this? 
One library who can permit to do this to you is **Volley** ,
 is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster. You can find all the benefits of the library here [Transmitting Network Data Using Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

I'm not using eclipse anymore to develop in android , rightnow i'm using **Android Studio** and I would like to show how i made working your app using the IDE and volley library :

**Dependencies to add to build.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
     package com.example.frank.wunderground;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        final String url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/<your_key>/conditions/q/Australia/Brisbane.json";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    // prepare the Request
            JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            // display response
                            //Log.d("Berly", response.toString());
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            try {
//version is not a Object it was a mistake in your code
                              //  JSONObject fullJson = response.getJSONObject("version"); 
                                JSONObject currentObservation = response.getJSONObject("current_observation");
                                JSONObject displayLocation = currentObservation.getJSONObject("display_location");
                               String full = displayLocation.getString("full");
                                Log.d("Berly", full.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berly: "+full.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                           // Log.d("Error.Response", error);
                        }
                    }
            );
    // add it to the RequestQueue
            queue.add(getRequest);
        }
    }
```

**Results :** 
[image: Console log]

[image: full json file response]

[image: your desiderate result]