# How to turn JSON response with more rows into Java objects

Tags: java, php, android, json

I need to get a table from my database and turn it into a java array of objects. To make this I used this php code:

```
 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){  
    $response["success"] = true; 
    $response["tavolo"] = $tavolo;
    $response["pizza"] = $pizza;
    $response["quantita"] = $quantita;
    $response["note"] = $note;
    array_push($arr, $response);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This should return for example this:

```
[{"success":true,"tavolo":"7","pizza":"Wurstel","quantita":"1","note":""},{"success":true,"tavolo":"9","pizza":"Wurstel","quantita":"1","note":""}]
```

The problem is how to turn each row into a java object. I thought I could use the same way as when I have only a row and I have to create only one object.
For example (one row):

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
           JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
           Ordine o = new Ordine();
           o.setPizza(jsonResponse.getString("pizza"));
           o.setQuantità(jsonResponse.getString("quantita"));
           o.setNote(jsonResponse.getString("note"));
           t.getOrdini().add(o); //t contains an array of objects Ordine
           }catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
   };
   OrdiniDelGiorno ordiniDelGiorno = new OrdiniDelGiorno(responseListener);
   RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
   queue.add(ordiniDelGiorno);
```

But the response to manage was only one row like this

```
{"success":true,"tavolo":"7","pizza":"Wurstel","quantita":"1","note":""}
```

And it worked, but when the rows are more like:

```
[{"success":true,"tavolo":"7","pizza":"Wurstel","quantita":"1","note":""},{"success":true,"tavolo":"9","pizza":"Wurstel","quantita":"1","note":""}]
```

which logic should I implement?

Comment: Yesterday i answered to a question and maybe you can find this useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601822/jsonobject-must-begin-with-at-character-1character-2-line-1/44606894#44606894)

Comment: @Frank I have read your answer but it didn't help me

Comment: If you run your backend on the browser , is it returning what you are expecting ?