# JSON request wit AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, asynchronous, client-server

I am trying to use AsyncHttpClient to make a JSON request. I tried to use several implementations, including setBody and addBodyPart, and many more. The result is always the same.

It should send a string like this converted to bytes:

```
{
  "template": "c=KZ;o=Template;cn=GOST_RAUTIL_USER_1Y;",
  "useHSM": "true",
  "altAttrs": {
    "altDN": [
      "CN=Test org1, SERIALNUMBER=1111111111",
      "CN=Test org2, SERIALNUMBER=2222222222"
    ]
  },
  "keyName": "XkjCPFLfvJCUYktH",
  "dn": "C=KZ, O=TEST, CN= XkjCPFLfvJCUYktH",
  "internalHSMkey": "true"
}
```

But somehow it converts the request into this:

> ..an ip
>   address.. POST    headers:    Content-Type:application/json   Authorization:Basic
>   SWdvcjpHYW1tYTIwMTk=

So the server gets a wrong request and responses with an error meessage:

> A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 0 [character 1 line 1] json:

Here is one of my code implementations:

```
  Request request = new RequestBuilder(POST)
            .setUrl(apiUrl)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()))
            .setBody(jsonObject.toString().getBytes())
            .build();

asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(request, new AsyncCompletionHandlerBase() {
            @Override
            public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
            }

            @Override
            public org.asynchttpclient.Response onCompleted(org.asynchttpclient.Response response) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("COMPLETED");
                return super.onCompleted(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe, because you use `.setBody(jsonObject.toString().getBytes())`? Why do you need send that as `Bytes`?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4773688/2987755

Comment: I need it to be sent as Bytes because the server receives it in Bytes. Still, if I use it like .setBody(jsonObject.toString()) - it gives the same result